# Remove Duplicate Values from Javascript Array BUT only values duplicated more than 5 times

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a big data array and I need a reliable way of extracting the appropriate value as well as implementing de-duplication all-in-one.

As impartial values are placed into my array, I need to extract a value from my array that occurs at least 5 or more times...

Here's what I got:

```
var data=['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','5','5','5','5','6','7','7','7','7','7','7']

var uniqueArray = data.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return data.indexOf(elem) == pos;
});
for (var i=0; i<uniqueArray.length;i++){
    console.log(uniqueArray); 
};
```

The above code functions properly to remove duplicate values when I attempt to add:

```
var uniqueArray = data.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return data.indexOf((elem) == pos) > 5;
});
for (var i=0; i<uniqueArray.length;i++){
    console.log(uniqueArray); 
};
```

This does not function... I receive no values.

What i expect to receive is only 1 and 7 in the new array

Plz help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implement a Hash table! You want 5 indices, but index more than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to build an index (named `counts` in the snippet below) that represents how many times each value is present in the array:

```js
const data = ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','5','5','5','5','6','7','7','7','7','7','7'];

const counts = data.reduce((result, value) => {
  result[value] = (result[value] || 0) + 1;
  return result;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(counts).filter(value => counts[value] >= 5);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, if your array is sorted, you can eliminate the need for the `counts` object by using a more procedural solution:

```js
const data = ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','5','5','5','5','6','7','7','7','7','7','7'];

let current;
let count = 0;
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let value = data[i];
  
  if (value !== current) {
    count = 0;
    current = value;
  }
  
  if (++count === 5) {
    result.push(value);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That does seem to be working!!! Many thanks! How is this snippet in terms of performance? Is it a pretty light solution?

Comment: Well, you have the additional overhead of creating the index object. (Currently all answers to your questions use this approach.) If your array is always sorted like it is in your example, it would be possible to come up with a more procedural solution that would remove the need for an index object.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `map` which contains value and its occurrences then extract the values from `map` based on occurences.

```js
var data = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7']

var map = data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  if(acc[item]) acc[item] += 1;
  else acc[item] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(map).filter(function(key) {
  return map[key] >= 5;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var data=['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','5','5','5','5','6','7','7','7','7','7','7']

// Create an index mapping of format <value in data array>: <number of occurances>
var map = data.reduce((map, value)=>{
   if (map[value]) 
      map[value]++ // If occurred one or more times, we increment the occurrence count
   else
      map[value] = 1 // If first time occurrence, we set number of occurrences to 1
   return map // return updated index map to reducer
}, {})

// Then we iterate through the index mapping
Object.keys(map).forEach((key)=>{
   if(map[key] > 5) console.log(key) // Note: Here we should print the  key, not the map[key]
})
```